# Exactness Part of Eilenberg-Steenrod Axioms and Its Relation with Singular Homology

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, homology-cohomology

I am reviewing algebraic topology using Bredon's book Topology and Geometry, and I have a conceptual question on the [Eilenberg-Steenrod Axioms](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Eilenberg-SteenrodAxioms.html), in particular the first item about exactness. The part of the statement that got my attention is that in the long exact sequence of the pair $(X,A)$, the homomorphism $j_*:H_n(X)\to H_n(X,A)$ is actually induced by the inclusion $j:(X,\emptyset)\to (X,A)$.

But, we know that in singular homology theory, the homomorphism $j_*:H_n(X)\to H_n(X,A)$ is induced by the quotient map on the chain $j_\sharp: C_n(X)\to C_n(X,A)$ where $C_n(X,A):=C_n(X)/C_n(A).$ If we take the inclusion map $j:(X,\emptyset)\to (X,A)$ literally, it means we include $X$ into $X$ and include $\emptyset$ into $A$. And if we use the definition of induced chain maps $f_\sharp:C_n(X)\to C_n(Y)$ from the map $f:X\to Y$ where
$$
f_\sharp(\sum_i n_i\sigma_i)=\sum_i n_i(f\circ\sigma_i)
$$
with $\sigma_i: \Delta^n\to X$ a singular chain, then I don't understand how the inclusion $j:(X,\emptyset)\to (X,A)$ will actually induce a map $j_*:H_n(X)\to H_n(X,A)$ that coincides with the map induced by the quotient map $j_\sharp: C_n(X)\to C_n(X)/C_n(A)$.

I would appreciate any helps and explanation. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is an **answer** to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to **clarify**, not answer the question. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)** for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list. Also notice that comments are not indexed by the full text search, don't have any revision history, can only be edited for 5 minutes and allow only limited markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, in algebra, if we have a homomorphism $g:V\to W$ which maps a subgroup/submodule $V'\subseteq V$ to some subgroup/submodule $W'\subseteq W$ then it induces a well defined map $g':V/V'\to W/W'$, $g'([v])=[g(v)]$.

Here, given a continuous map $f:(X,A)\to (Y,B)$, it induces a homomorphism on chains $C_n(X)\to C_n(Y)$ which maps $C_n(A)$ to $C_n(B)$. Therefore it induces a well defined homomorphism $C_n(X)/C_n(A)\to C_n(Y)/C_n(B)$.

In the particular case of $j:(X,\emptyset)\to (X,A)$ this means that $j$ induces a map $j_\sharp: C_n(X)/C_n(\emptyset)\to C_n(X)/C_n(A)$. It just happens that $C_n(\emptyset)=0$ and thus the first component can be replaced by $C_n(X)$. And so our $j$ induces maps $C_n(X)\to C_n(X)/C_n(A)$, which then are compatible with those chain complexes, and so induce a map on homologies $H_n(X)\to H_n(X,A)$.

Comment: Oh that makes sense! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

This is just an extended comment to freakish's answer.

What Bredon does is a slight abuse of notation. When he introduces singular homology, he starts with the singular chain complex $\Delta_*(X)$ of a space $X$ and obtains its homology groups
$$H_p(X) = H_p(\Delta_*(X)) .$$
For a pair $(X,A)$ he defines
$$\Delta_r(X,A) = \Delta_r(X)/\Delta_r(A) \tag{1}$$
to obtain the singular chain complex $\Delta_*(X,A)$ of $(X,A)$. Here is the first abuse of notation: $\Delta_r(A)$ is not a genuine subgroup of $\Delta_r(X)$. The elements of $\Delta_r(A)$ are maps $\Delta^r \to A$ and these are no maps $\Delta^r \to X$ because the codomains do not agree. However, the inclusion $i : A \to X$ indces a natural homomorphism $\Delta_r(i) : \Delta_r(A) \to \Delta_r(X),\Delta^(i)(\sigma) = i \circ \sigma$. This embeds $\Delta_r(A)$ as a subgroup of $\Delta_r(X)$. In fact, $\Delta_r(i)(\Delta_r(A)) = \{ \tau : \Delta^r \to X \mid \tau (\Delta^r) \subset A \}$. Formally correct one should define
$$\Delta_r(X,A) = \Delta_r(X)/\Delta_r(i)(\Delta_r(A)) . \tag{2}$$
But $(1)$ is a very minor abuse of notation.

Next he defines $j : \Delta_*(X) \to \Delta_*(X,A)$ to be the chain map given by the quotient homomorphisms $\Delta_r(X) \to \Delta_r(X,A)$ and gets homomorphisms
$$j_* : H_p(X) \to H_p(X,A) .$$

Unfortunately he misses to define induced homomorphisms $f_* : H_p(X,A) \to H_p(Y,B)$ for maps of pairs $f : (X,A) \to (Y,B)$, but freakish has explained how this is done. In the chapter "Axioms for Homology" Bredon actually works with functors $H_p$ from the category of topological pairs to the category of abelian groups.

This axiomatic framework is primarily based on "relative groups" $H_p(X,A)$. However, Bredon *defines* "absolute groups" as $H_p(X) = H_p(X,\emptyset)$.

Concerning singular homology this results in another abuse of notation. Actually the chain complex $\Delta_*(X,\emptyset)$ is not identical with $ \Delta_*(X)$, thus $H_p(X)$ and $H_p(X,\emptyset)$ are formally distinct. But again this is a very minor abuse of notation: The groups $\Delta_r(X)/\Delta_r(\emptyset) = \Delta_r(X)/0$ and $\Delta_r(X)$ are canonically isomorphic. Using this identification, we see that the above $j_* : H_p(X) \to H_p(X,A)$ is nothing else than the homomorphism $j_* : H_p(X,\emptyset) \to H_p(X,A)$ induced by the map of pairs $j : (X,\emptyset) \to (X,A), j(x) = x$.